# Pages inside a page (with thumbnails)

Tags: loop, thumbnails, wp-list-pages

I´m building a actors/movies sites and I got stuck with one thing. I have several pages with actors biography (featured image, name, about, date of birth, etc) and I have a menu with the option "actors". I would like to create a page called "actors" that could loop all actors pages with pagination, organizing them in one, two or three columns and five to ten lines. I have search a plugin/widget to do that, but I wasn´t lucky. Could anyone here help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, you need to create a template that list all your pages (actors) on one template.

If this is the case, you need to create the actor archive template to allow you to:

- Add a page where you can list all your actors
- Left the page template intact

So, the template that you need to create is archive-actors.php

Then, on this template, you need to customise the query to loop throughout all your page and display the content to the page (links, thumbnail etc)

You can use this code:

```
$pages = get_pages(); 
foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); 
    $title = $page_data->post_title; 
    echo $content; 
}
```

Otherwise, for more advance options, use Wp_query with post_type=page.

Hope this help.

Note: I will never have created pages for actors. The best solution is to use a custom post type actors. This will allow you to create custom taxonomy and be able to search for actors and add many nice features (CMS nice and clean, ability to use taxonomy + CPT wp templates)

Answer (score 2):

You want to query for the pages on the current site? `WP_Query` is your friend!

first tell it what we want

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'page'
);
```

then create the query

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

now check if it found any pages

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
```

If it did, do a standard posts loop:

```
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // display the page as you see fit
        the_title();
        the_content();
    }
```

Then clean up after ourselves:

```
    wp_reset_postdata();
```

If it didn't find any pages, put a message in the else bit:

```
} else {
    // there are no pages?!
}
```

It should look very similar to a standard main loop. This is what `get_posts` and `get_pages` use internally.

Comment: Why not use `get_template_part()` inside the loop, instead of  `the_title(); the content();`?

Comment: You can! I only put the_title and the_content to demonstrate that inside the loop you do things